# error pulling postgres on windows using thingsboard/tb-postgres

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, terminal, thingsboard

I got an error when pulling postgre for thingsboard on docker windows

The pulling wasnt completed, and it says:
**invalid character 'c' looking for beginning of value**

its always error even after creating docker volume as the documentation said.

can anyone help me solve this problem so i can pull postgres on docker windows?
thankyou

OS:Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

Just tried pulling the image on windows 10

In my case everything worked fine:

```
docker pull thingsboard/tb-postgres
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from thingsboard/tb-postgres
ffbb094f4f9e: Pull complete
0c8eb0702926: Pull complete
298f32cef190: Pull complete
b8d314694c3c: Pull complete
83e0d1c36c4f: Pull complete
de2d6501c95a: Pull complete
d38413442fef: Pull complete
b22f2fcabf27: Pull complete
5845b95c6c6a: Pull complete
512940fe4832: Pull complete
c09b3750140c: Pull complete
8bd36e91c307: Pull complete
172c7c1e53fe: Pull complete
dfcecd4baf49: Pull complete
27cf92a2adb9: Pull complete
1c8a3d27af9e: Pull complete
b977bd73820c: Pull complete
cc2d419dece3: Pull complete
4907be36a3ee: Pull complete
d3b283f7f8a6: Pull complete
a7ad9c8e0806: Pull complete
66f4ceabc4d9: Pull complete
90b220518e0f: Pull complete
118b793875dd: Pull complete
9131c7ca2cc7: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b4b9d2094b80bb05e58e3ac157aeabc253b6aa6c401ba6d7fa338e13462bf19f
Status: Downloaded newer image for thingsboard/tb-postgres:latest
docker.io/thingsboard/tb-postgres:latest
```